# Grabbing specific value from subject string of email

Tags: power-automate

I have a trigger for Gmail "When new email arrives"

I take the subject and throw this into the Lead > Topic.

I would like to rip out the phone # and throw that into our mobile phone field.
I'd also like to rip out the keyword and put that into it's own field.

Any idea how I can take this subject where the keyword and phone # will be different and rip out those values from within Power Automate?

`The keyword TestKeyword for TEST was requested by 18005550505`

Does power automate really not have any regex capabilities outside of paid third party connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Automate does not support regex, but does have some decent string manipulation capabilities. If the Subject of the email will **ALWAYS** be the same, you can use a simple split then select the position of each desired value from the array:

**Example:**

- Compose 1: Get the string from email subject
- Compose 2: `split(outputs('the_string'), ' ')`
- Compose 3: `outputs('the_split')[2]`
- Compose 4: `outputs('the_split')[8]`

Then do what you want with the results.

[image]

[image]

[image]